# Change order on Foundation with three columns

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to achieve the following layout in Foundation. Which push-pull classes should I use to make the last column go above one column in desktop?

```
      <div class="row">
         <div class="small-12 column large-10">
          First on mobile, First on desktop
          </div>
         <div class="small-12 large-12 column">
         Second on mobile, Third on desktop
         </div>
         <div class="small-12 column large-2>
         Third on mobile, Second on desktop
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: If I did undarstande it right, yuo want the last colmun placed on middle, right?

Comment: Yes. In desktop I want to have first the large-10 and then the last column large-2 next to each other and then the large-12.

Comment: Order on mobile 1,2,3. Order on desktop 1,3,2.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a couple syntax errors in your example there. Secondly, you have the class `column` when it should be `columns`.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="small-12 columns large-10">
      First on mobile, First on desktop
      </div>
     <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
     Second on mobile, Third on desktop
     </div>
     <div class="small-12 columns large-2">
     Third on mobile, Second on desktop
    </div>
 </div>
```

Also, I don't think you can push/pull anything 12 columns if 12 is your columns per row. I would do a work-around of sorts with hiding/displaying that second/third item. Something like the below.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="small-12 columns large-10">
      First on mobile, First on desktop
      </div>
     <div class="small-12 columns large-2 show-for-large-up">
     Third on mobile, Second on desktop
    </div>                    
     <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
     Second on mobile, Third on desktop
     </div>
     <div class="small-12 columns large-2 show-for-medium-down">
     Third on mobile, Second on desktop
    </div>                             
 </div>
```

Maybe there's an elegant way to reorder the html through foundation that I don't know about. But I'd use this as a temporary fix until you can find something more concrete.

Comment: column and columns are the same thing.

Comment: In this case, hide/show approach It is impractical and dirty "solution". By the way, columns an column stays for same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't!

Since one column with 12 it's almost like one row.

Thus you cannot push/pull columns from one row to another. It's only possible move it along the same row. In other words, when there's 2 or more divs (not one with width of 12 columns).

In fact, you should use and leverage of Foundation [Javascript Utilities](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript-utilities.html), like `matchMedia()` or `Foundation.utils.is_x` functions.

So you can to check if the browser currently matches the media query passed in as a string to matchMedia() or use the default Foundation media queries available methods:

```
if (Foundation.utils.is_large_only()) {
    //do something...
} else if (Foundation.utils.is_small_up()) {
    //do something...
}
```

I strongly advise you to read the Foundation doc (JavaScript Utilities > Media Queries section) in order to understand how it works.

Comment: So the only option is thru duplicating and then hiding accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 column large-10" style="background:red;">
    First on mobile, First on desktop
   </div>
   <div class="small-12 column large-2 show-for-large-up" style="background:green;">
   Second on desktop
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 column  large-12" style="background:blue;">
  Third on desktop, Second on mobile
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 column show-for-small-only" style="background:yellow;">
  Third on mobile
  </div>
</div>
```